# SlimDX 2D Device creation

Tags: .net, directx, directx-9, slimdx

I've dabbled in XNA but since it's end of life, I'd like to move on to SlimDX.

I'm attempting to create something 2D with several layers drawn over each other. I'd ideally like to target DX9

My understanding is that Direct2D sits on top of Direct3D and as such I need to create a 3D Device and then use that in the creation of a 2D device.

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble with creating the device, and the examples I've found are not entirely clear (at least to me).

I'm unclear what components I should be using - Direct3D9/DXGI(?)/etc. I assume that I don't really want to refer to anything in the `SlimDX.Direct3D10` namespace, however, I can't find equivalent types in `Direct3D9` which match the examples I'm following.

The following throws `DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED: Unsupported.` on DX9 hardware (not unexpected). What's the DX9 equivalent?

```vb
Public Shared Sub Main()
    Window = New RenderForm()
    InitialiseDevice()
    MessagePump.Run(Window, Sub()

            End Sub)
    Cleanup()
End Sub

Private Property D3DDevice As SlimDX.Direct3D10_1.Device1
Private Property Window As SlimDX.Windows.RenderForm

Private Sub InitialiseDevice()

    Dim Desc = New SwapChainDescription() With {
         .BufferCount = 1,'
         .ModeDescription = New ModeDescription(Window.ClientSize.Width, Window.ClientSize.Height, New Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
         .IsWindowed = True,
         .OutputHandle = Window.Handle,
         .SampleDescription = New SampleDescription(1, 0),
         .SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
         .Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
    }

    Dim SwapChain As SwapChain

    SlimDX.
        Direct3D10_1.
        Device1.
        CreateWithSwapChain(
            Nothing,
            DriverType.Hardware,
            DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport,
            SlimDX.Direct3D10_1.FeatureLevel.Level_10_1,
            Desc,
            D3DDevice,
            SwapChain)
    ....


End Sub
```

Comment: Then the hardware might not support feature level 10.1. Set an appropriate level that is supported. You can also have a look at the [SlimDX Sprite Text Renderer](http://sdxspritetext.codeplex.com/) which uses Direct3D (version 11). You can also use it with DX9 devices by specifying the correct feature level.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the device in question doesn't support 10.1 - Gpu-Z reports it as a DX9 card. (Long story short, about a day into deciding to write this, my normal Gfx card died (overheating) so I've swapped in an old one. It occured to me that nothing I'm doing should require 10+ so I might as well target 9, continue development with the old card for testing purposes and go from there). So, I'm looking for a DX9 only solution. Thanks for the Text Renderer link which I wasn't aware of, very handy

Comment: You can develop for DX9 cards with DX11 or DX10. DirectX is just the library. by specifying the FeatureLevel in `CreateWithSwapChain` you define which hardware you need.